# Is it possible to show the scale in an OSM tile plot using bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh, scale, openstreetmap

I am using the OSM tile provider in bokeh to plot a basemap, here is a [reference](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/geo.html). I am wondering if there is a way to show the scale of the map in meters or kilometers depending on the zoom level.

Just to clarify, the axis labels can remain in WGS84-pseudo-mercator but I want to have a scale or some sort of ruler to give a better sense of the distances in the plot.

Below is an example image from the OSM website where I have marked the scale in the bottom left corner.

---

Edit: I have found out that there is currently no such feature build into bokeh, [here](https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/is-it-possible-to-show-the-scale-in-an-osm-tile-plot-using-bokeh/8535). I have opened a feature request on github, [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/11755).
I am also interested in any work-around, e.g. using annotations.

[image]